# Using Tkinter function to create multiple drop-down menus and allowing user to select and display different options

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently facing an issue where I am not able to get a different distinct output from each drop-down menu in Tkinter.

The aim of my code is to get a similar output in the following image attached: "Output of ideal, expected result".
[image]

However, this is the current result that I am getting, which is attached in:"Current Result".
[image]

Below is my attached code.

I would greatly appreciate any form of advice or help on this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TestFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dimension =('106','108','110','112','114','126','128','130','132','134','136','138','140','146','148','150','152','154','360','380','400','420','440','500', '520', '540',
                        '560', '580', '600','780','800','820')
        self.option_var = tk.IntVar(self)
        #self.create_widgets()
        #self.create_widgets_1()
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        label = ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_X1:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        #ODD_X1
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed)
        option_menu.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_Y1:').grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed)
        option_menu.grid(column=4, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_X2:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed)
        option_menu.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_Y2:').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed)
        option_menu.grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=4, row=5, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
   
 def option_changed(self, *args):
        self.output_label['text'] = f'You selected: {self.option_var.get()}'

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("800x400")
        self.title('ABC')
        for r in range(5):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(8):
            self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        
        self.testFrame1 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
App().mainloop()
```

Comment: You have assigned the same ```variable``` to all 4 option menus. I t is being constantly updated as you select an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue: All of your option menus have the same variable `self.option_menu`. When you select any option, it updates the variable. Hence, the best option is to change the variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TestFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dimension =('106','108','110','112','114','126','128','130','132','134','136','138','140','146','148','150','152','154','360','380','400','420','440','500', '520', '540',
                        '560', '580', '600','780','800','820')
        self.option_var = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.option_var1 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.option_var2 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.option_var3 = tk.IntVar(self)
        #self.create_widgets()
        #self.create_widgets_1()
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        label = ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_X1:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        #ODD_X1
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed)
        option_menu.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_Y1:').grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var1,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed1)
        option_menu.grid(column=4, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label1 = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label1.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_X2:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var2,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed2)
        option_menu.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label2 = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label2.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        ttk.Label(self,  text='Select the dimension for ODD_Y2:').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var3,
            self.dimension[0],
            *self.dimension,
            command=self.option_changed3)
        option_menu.grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
        self.output_label3 = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label3.grid(column=4, row=4, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)
   
    def option_changed(self, *args):
        self.output_label['text'] = f'You selected: {self.option_var.get()}'
    def option_changed1(self, *args):
        self.output_label1['text'] = f'You selected: {self.option_var1.get()}'
    def option_changed2(self, *args):
        self.output_label2['text'] = f'You selected: {self.option_var2.get()}'
    def option_changed3(self, *args):
        self.output_label3['text'] = f'You selected: {self.option_var3.get()}'

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("800x400")
        self.title('ABC')
        for r in range(5):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(8):
            self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        
        self.testFrame1 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is able to work already!

Comment: Happy to help, Welcome @etfl2021